# Cox multi-state model - CIF confidence intervals

Tags: r, survival

Is it possible to get confidence intervals for the estimated CIF from a `survival::coxph` multi-state model?

This code produces the cumulative incidence function, but there are no options to get confidence intervals:

```
library(survival)

# 0 = Censored, 1 = Relapse, 2 = Death
rotterdam$status = ifelse(rotterdam$recur == 1, 1,
                          ifelse(rotterdam$death == 1, 2, 0))
rotterdam$time = pmin(rotterdam$rtime, rotterdam$dtime)

# Competing risks Cox model
m = coxph(Surv(time, as.factor(status)) ~ hormon, data = rotterdam, id = pid)

# Plot CIF for people without hormone replacement therapy
s = survfit(m, newdata = data.frame(hormon = c(0)))
plot(s, col = c('red', 'blue'), xlab = 'Time since diagnosis (days)',
     ylab = 'CIF') # Plots s$pstate[, 1, ] against time
legend(x = 0, y = 0.58, legend = c('Relapse', 'Relapse free death'), 
       col = c('red', 'blue'), lty = 1)
```

Essentially I'm after adding confidence intervals to the lines in the plots.

I'm happy to use a different package if needed, but it needs to be a Cox model & not a Fine-Grey model.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A confidence interval about what?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent sorry I should have said - about the cumulative incidence function. I've added more info to the question

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this stuff, so I'm really not sure of what I do below. See [the competing risks vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) and `?finegray`. Below I follow the `?finegray` example.

````r
etime <- with(rotterdam, ifelse(recur == 0, dtime, rtime))
event <- with(rotterdam, ifelse(recur == 0, 2*death, 1))
event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels = c("censor", "recur", "death"))

pdata <- finegray(Surv(etime, event) ~ ., data = rotterdam)

fgfit <- coxph(Surv(fgstart, fgstop, fgstatus) ~ hormon,
               weight = fgwt, data = pdata)

sf <- survfit(
  fgfit, 
  newdata = data.frame(hormon = c(0, 1)), 
  se.fit = TRUE,
  conf.int = 0.95
)

summary_sf <- summary(sf)
# confidence bounds:
summary_sf$lower
summary_sf$upper
```
````